# Mostrar datos en selets

Tags: php

Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar un dato de una fila, te muestre en los selects
Mas abajo tengo mis lista que datos que al hacer clic en uno de ellos debe cargar los datos en los selects e imput. Ya he intentado de varias maneras pero no he podido encontrar una solución a esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero solo me carga en el imput, no así en los selects

```
<label class="col-sm-1 control-label no-padding-right"> Cláusulas </label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <select name="claus_nro" id="claus_nro" class="chosen-select form-control editable" data-placeholder="Seleccione...">
        <option value="0"> </option>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT claus_nro, claus_desc, claus_obs FROM causulas order by claus_desc asc";
        $resultado = pg_query($conexion, $sql);
        while ($datos = pg_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $datos['claus_nro'] ?>"><?php echo $datos['claus_desc'] ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

AJAX

```js
function listarDetalles(){
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:"controladorDetalles.php",
        data:{
            contrato_serv_nro: $("#contrato_serv_nro").val()
        }
    }).done(function(resultadoDet){
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(resultadoDet));
        var lineas = "";
        for(rsd of resultadoDet){
            lineas += "<tr onclick='seleccionDetalle("+JSON.stringify(rsd)+")'>"
                lineas += "<td>";
                    lineas += rsd.tip_contra_desc;
                lineas += "</td>";
                lineas += "<td>";
                    lineas += rsd.claus_desc;
                lineas += "</td>";
                lineas += "<td>";
                    lineas += rsd.claus_obs;
                lineas += "</td>";
            lineas += "</tr>"
        }
        $("#grilla_detalles").html(lineas);
    }).fail(function(a,b,c){
        alert(c);
    })
}

function seleccionDetalle(json){
    Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key) {
        $("#"+key).val(json[key]);
    });
    $(".form-line").attr("class","form-line focused");
    $("#operacion_det").val("2");
}
```

Resultado del log de la función seleccionDetalle:

```
{
"contrato_serv_nro": "1",
"tip_contra_nro": "2",
"claus_nro": "1",
"contrato_serv_obs": "",
"tip_contra_desc": "Trabajo Zona Anden",
"claus_desc": "PRIMERO: ANTECEDENTES",
"claus_obs": "AQUI SE DESCRIBE LA CLAUSULA"
```

}

Comment: Hola Marco, ¿podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar **como texto** el resultado de hacer `console.log(json)` en la función `seleccionDetalle`? Gracias

Comment: Hola Marcos, procedí a lo que me has dicho. Desde ya gracias

Comment: Te paso [una prueba](https://jsfiddle.net/65801rgj/) donde todo funciona. Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos, ¡me sirvió mucho!